# Screen to staggered isometric grid algorithm

Tags: python, kivy, tiles, isometric, staggeredgridlayout

I'm working with Kivy and Pytmx, I need to get Grid Tile from Map Coordinates for staggered map.

[mymap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HjWQi.png)

My tile size is:

```
TILE_WIDTH = 256
TILE_HEIGHT = 149
```

When I used the isometric diamond grid, I calculated it like this:

```
def screen_to_isometric_grid(cartX, cartY):
    screenx = mh - cartY / (TILE_HEIGHT * SPRITE_SCALING) + cartX / (TILE_WIDTH * SPRITE_SCALING) - mw / 2 - 1 / 2
    screeny = mh - cartY / (TILE_HEIGHT * SPRITE_SCALING) - cartX / (TILE_WIDTH * SPRITE_SCALING) + mw / 2 - 1 / 2
    screenx2 = round(screenx)
    screeny2 = round(screeny)
    return screenx2, screeny2
```

Now I'm using staggered map and I dont know how to get tile coordinates.

I found algorithm in C++ here [enter link description here](https://coderoad.ru/35885029/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B5-%D1%81)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def subregion(px, py, r_x, r_y):
rx = int(r_x)
ry = int(r_y)
foo = px - py
bar = px + py
if foo < 0 and bar > 1:  # Top
    return [rx, ry]
elif foo < 0 and bar < 1:  # Left
    if r_y > 0:
        if py > 0.5:
            return [rx - 1, ry + 1]
        return [rx - 1, ry]
    else:
        return None
elif foo > 0 and bar > 1:  # Right
    if r_y > 0:
        if py > 0.5:
            return [rx, ry + 1]
        return [rx, ry]
    else:
        return None
elif foo > 0 and bar < 1:  # Bottom
    if r_y < 0:
        return [rx, ry]
    return [rx, ry + 1]
```